# How to find the first occurrence of a substring in a list of substrings?

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

I have a `List<string>` of substrings that *may* or may not be contained in a larger main string. Ex:

```
List<string> subStringList = new List<string>(){" at ", " @ "," near "," by "," above "};
List<string> searchStringList = new List<string>{
"GULF ISLAND POND NEAR LEWISTON, ME",
"South Branch Raritan River near High Bridge NJ",
"Susquehanna R near Browns Island at Dalmatia, PA",
"PARKS CREEK AT LYLE FIELD RD NEAR JEFFERSON, GA",
"HOMOSASSA R AT HOMOSASSA FL",
"ST. CLAIR RIVER NEAR ROBERTS LANDING, MI"
};
```

What I want to do is to find the element of `subStringList` which occurs **first** in a given search string and then return the searchString up to that point.

For example:

```
List<string> riverList = new List<string>();
foreach (var seachString in searchStringList)
{
    string river = seachString.ToLower();
    int minIndex = int.MaxValue;
    foreach (var subString in subStringList.Select(r => r.ToLower()).AsEnumerable())
    {
         var index = river.IndexOf(subString);
         if (index != null && index > -1 && index < minIndex)
             minIndex = index;
     }
         riverList.Add(seachString.Substring(0,minIndex));
}
```

The output should look something like this:

```
[0]: "GULF ISLAND POND"
[1]: "South Branch Raritan River"
[2]: "Susquehanna R"
[3]: "PARKS CREEK"
[4]: "HOMOSASSA R"
[5]: "ST. CLAIR RIVER"
```

The code I have seems to work but is there a more efficient way to do something like this and how could something like this be done with Linq?

Comment: Did you mean "What I want to do is to find the element of `subStringList` which occurs FIRST in a given search string and then return the searchString up to that point"

Comment: Yes, that is a better description of the problem.

Comment: In your current code... `Index != null` is unnecessary as IndexOf(ss) never returns null. Also if the string you are searching does NOT have one of the search strings... your current code will crash.

Comment: John, you are correct, I noticed that after running a few iterations on some data. I appreciate all the answers so far.

Comment: So what do you ask for, most efficient or a Linq solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice to have an overload for `String.IndexOfAny()` that takes `String[]` instead of `char[]`. Here's mine:

```
searchStringList.Select(s => s.SubstringAsFarAsIndexOfAny(subStringList));


public static class stringExt
{
    public static int IndexOfAny(this string s, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType=StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
    {
        var founds= anyOf.Select(sub=> s.IndexOf(sub,stringComparisonType)).Where(i => i>=0);
        return founds.Any() ? founds.Min() : -1;
    }

    public static string SubstringAsFarAsIndexOfAny(this string s, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType=StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        var foundIndex= s.IndexOfAny(anyOf,stringComparisonType);
        return foundIndex >=0 ? s.Substring(0, foundIndex) : s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite a neat solution, though in my understanding `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is a better choice, until and unless we are dealing with culture specific application, +1

Comment: `founds.Any() ? founds.Min() ` enumerates twice. You should really add a `ToArray()` to prevent this.

Comment: Should not. Any() doesn't enumerate & Where() and Select() both optimise for arrays, Lists & Iterators:  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,4158286b17727025

Comment: But I agree that to meet OP's 'as fast as possible' clause I would do overloads specific to Arrays. It's just that, unless you're doing it *millions* of times in a loop…

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll Any() needs to enumerate until it finds one element for there Where-Condition. Min will enumerate again to find the one with the lowest. The fact that there are arrays involed doenst count since there is a Where and a Select involed.

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll As a proove to what i just said: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hRLOl9 Your extension method with a Console.WriteLine to count the enumerations. It should be one `#` according to you, but its two.

Comment: I see your point: I was thinking that .Any() would be constant time, but because of the Where() clause it isn't. —//— And I didn't expect the double call to Select(). Interesting. —//— And still … I'm reluctant to add ToArray() as a one-size-fits-all solution because you don't know whether that's going to create a copy–which would be a *complete* enumeration–followed by the search for Min()–which would be a second *complete* enumeration. So that, on average, would be worse.
An overload for string[] or for ICollection<string> would be better? Then the Count or Length replaces the Any()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with linq:

```
var result = from str in searchStringList
             from substr in subStringList
             let index = str.IndexOf(substr, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
             where index > -1
             select str.Remove(index);
```

Comment: This returns more output rows than input rows. www.Linqpad.net is good for testing snippets :-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED (for cases when there is matching substring in the substringList): here is a one-string solution with default LINQ methods without any extensions:

```
var result = searchStringList
                .Select(searchString =>
                    searchString.Substring(0,
                        subStringList.Select(
                                substring => searchString.IndexOf(substring, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                            .Where(s => s > -1)                            
                            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                            .Min()))
                            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
```

Comment: Is is possible to write your code to not crash if the searched strings are NOT in the string searched?

Comment: Updated for the case you mentioned

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work as expected using LINQ. Is there a way to address the issue where the searched string is at the begging of the string like: " @ ST. CLAIR RIVER ROBERTS LANDING, MI"? your code does not seem to identify these lines.

Comment: It works fine for such case. You don't see that line because the index of " @ " is 0 and when we call the substring method we get an empty string as the result which is filtered by the last Where.

Answer (score 0):

The general Linq alternative to a for loop is `Aggregate()`:

```
searchStringList.Select(s => s.SubstringAsFarAsIndexOfAny(subStringList));


public static class stringExt
{
    public static int IndexOfAny(this string s, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType=StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
    {
    var best = anyOf
                .Select(sub =>  s.IndexOf(sub, stringComparisonType))
                .Aggregate(
                        int.MaxValue,
                        (bestSoFar, current) => 0 <= current && current < bestSoFar ? current : bestSoFar
                    );
    return best == int.MaxValue ? -1 : best;
    }

    public static string SubstringAsFarAsIndexOfAny(this string s, IEnumerable<string> anyOf, StringComparison stringComparisonType=StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    {
        var foundIndex= s.IndexOfAny(anyOf,stringComparisonType);
        return foundIndex >=0 ? s.Substring(0, foundIndex) : s;
    }
}
```

I doubt that many people would find this more readable though.